# How to redirect browser during an Async Postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, postback, asp.net-3.5

## **The scenario**

I have an ASP.NET project which uses a custom authorization/authentication method (vs. using forms/windows authentication, etc.). On each *secure* page load, the following code is executed:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsLoggedIn)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Login/", true);
    }
}
```

This code basically checks whether the user is *still* logged in (no expired ASP.NET session, not logged out, etc.); if the user is not logged in, a `Response.Redirect()` happens, sending them to the login page.

This scenario **works perfectly fine** when the user requests a full page (through a link, or direct URL). The issue arises when using an **async postback**!

I have a button nested inside of an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`, which cause async postbacks when clicked. This button updates an `<asp:Label />`. For example:

```html
<!-- the button -->
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyButton" CausesValidation="false" Text="My Button" OnClick="MyButton_Click" runat="server" />

<!-- the label -->
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" />
```

```cs
protected void MyButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

## **The issue**

When an async postback is executing, and `IsLoggedIn` is false, the request is *redirected* to the login page. Now, the ASP.NET Framework expects a specific response (rather than an HTML page); thus, throwing the following error:

[image]

## **The question**

**How can I solve this issue? How can I force the whole page redirect to a specific address from the code-behind during an async postback?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger from the code-behind you can do this:

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatepanelid, typeof(string), "redirect", "window.location = 'http://www.google.com';", true);
} else {
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Also note that if you use `window.open()`, a popup window will be opened (which may or may not be blocked). If you use `window.location = "someurl";` it will just do a client-side redirect.

Comment: While your answer is the most *appropriate* way of achieve the desired result, I needed a little bit **more** than that; I need to **interrupt** the page life cycle in its current state (as `Response.Redirect("path", true)` does). I've posted an additional answer providing this extra detail.

Answer (score 4):

While [Kenneth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775541/238722) is the appropriate method of redirecting, I needed something a little more *custom*.

During an async postback, I needed to simulate [`Response.Redirect("path", true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) - the **`true`** parameter *(Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate)* is the **important** thing I needed to replicate! Simply using `Response.End()` after `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` would not work because then there would be no response sent back to the browser.

By analyzing the server response to an async postback, I resorted to using the following hack (simulating a response by using `Response.Write`):

```cs
String jsRedirect = String.Format("window.location.pathname = '{0}';", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(url));

Response.Write(
    // required parameters!
    "0|asyncPostBackControlIDs|||" +
    "0|postBackControlIDs|||" +
    "0|updatePanelIDs|||" +
    "0|childUpdatePanelIDs|||" +
    "0|panelsToRefreshIDs|||" +

    // your custom JavaScript
    String.Format("{0}|scriptBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|{1}|", jsRedirect.Length, jsRedirect)
);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Great answer with great detail. Really, with the constraint that you want to abort the processing of the current request, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is some terminology misunderstanding here. "Async postback" is not technically a postback at all; it is an `xmlHttpRequest`. If you want to do a redirect here, it must be done in javascript in an ajax callback function using `window.open()`.

I'm not sure how you would implement this using asp.net AJAX. During the execution of your xmlHttpRequest code on the server, it is *impossible* to redirect a client (clarification - you *may* redirect, but the html you respond with will be (as in your case) incorrectly parsed by asp.NET's javascript ajax code.

With jQuery, this would be a pseudo-solution.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'redirect') {
            window.open('yourRedirectUrl');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on terminology - Unfortunately, I'm merely using the term that is widely used in the ASP.NET WebForms world. And how would I go about catching these redirects? As you can see they are *not* intentional redirects, but a side-effect of authorization/authentication.